# how to invoke terminal.app from a php script?

Tags: php, terminal, xcodebuild

I want to invoke terminal.app from a php script is this possible if not then how do we invoke terminal using applescript/shell script. I want to use php because there is no other option for me. also after invoking terminal i want to navigate to a folder and run xcodebuild command from there. Does someone knows about it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) command. But I fail to see how opening the terminal helps you.

Comment: not working. I am on MAC OS X Leopard. i want to build an iphone app using php on server then create ipa so that user can download the app and install through itunes